# open stage after task is completed JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I want to run a task and at the same time I want a progressbar. I found how to do both threads at the same time, but now I want the Stage with progressbar to close when the task is completed (when getTeller() == 1380) and open a new Stage.
can someone help me? This is what i already have (it shows the progressbar but the progressbar never closes).

```
                progressStage = new Stage();                
                progressStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);                  

                VBox root6 = new VBox(2);
                task = new Task<Integer>() {
                    @Override
                    public Integer call() throws Exception{
                        n = new Netwerk(bestand);//this is where the count starts to 1380
                        if(n.getTeller()==1380){


                            progressStage.close();
                            SaveStage = new Stage();
                            SaveStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                            ...//here I do the layout part

                        }
                        return null;

                    }
                 };

                pb = new ProgressBar();
                pb.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
                new Thread(task).start();

                Label lg = new Label("Even geduld...");
                root6.getChildren().addAll(lg,pb);
                Scene scene5 = new Scene(root6,300,200);
                progressStage.setTitle("TreinSysteem");
                progressStage.setResizable(false);
                progressStage.setScene(scene5);
                progressStage.show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure that your `Task` ends when your conditions are met (in your case: the count is `1380`), e.g. with a simple `return null`.
2. Use [`task.setOnSucceeded()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#setOnSucceeded-javafx.event.EventHandler-) to do something once the `Task` has finished its work. In your case: Open a new `Stage` and hide the `ProgressBar`.

Comment: but then i have two times return nul, isn't that a problem?

Comment: @MiLo Since you are not using the `Task` to compute a specific value, it does not matter.

Comment: and where do i write the task.setOnSucceeded()? Does it need to be in the call()?

Comment: Can i just use setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>)?

Comment: That is the one I was talking about (event linked to the docs) ;)